# Showing the video of the link shared on Whatsapp for Android Java or kotlin on Whatsapp

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, whatsapp

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, videoLink);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I can send the link containing the video to someone on WhatsApp, however, I want to show the image of the video to the user on WhatsApp.

Is there a way to do this in java or kotlin

[image]

as in the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're trying to do exactly but there are two options I can think of.

Firstly, if you're looking for something like what you have in the screenshot then no coding is required.

- This is usually handled by Facebook when their bot scrapes the meta tags from the page that is shared.
- If you wanted to accelerate this process you can manually put the link that you want to share in [Facebook's Sharing Debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRfMcO7pwfk) and scrape it manually so that Facebook takes note of it.
- Once that is done you can share the link and it should display video information including the image, title & description.

---

However, if you want to share only the video image/thumbnail you can do that as follows:

- grab the video ID from the URL using REGEX or by taking a substring of the URL that holds the ID.
- Plug that ID in one of the following URLs to get a link to an image that you can share instead of the video.
- `https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg`
- `https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg`
- `https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg`
- `https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg`
- `https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg`

---

Thanks to @asaph for his details answer on getting Youtube thumbnail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/2317116)